# laravel join select max of joined column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 table [products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7qq.png), [details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XapsT.png) and
[detail_colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S0ka.png)

I want `select max "stock" from "detail_colors"` and
`max "price" from "details"`

```
$products = Product::
           join('details', function (JoinClause $join) {
               $join->on('products.id', '=', 'details.product_id');

           })
           ->join('detail_colors', function (JoinClause $join) {
               $join->on('products.id', '=', 'detail_colors.product_id');
           })
           ->select('products.*', DB::raw('max(details.price) as price'), DB::raw('max(detail_colors.stock) as stock'))
```

and its not working.

I use laravel 8.*

Comment: Don't you want to use eloquent models and relationships?

Comment: You need add ->get() to end

Comment: my problem not add ->get();
my problem is i cant select maximum value from another tables.

Comment: @shaedrich
i use relationships. beacuase i need to order by price and stock from two other tables. i used join.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use aggregate functions on relationships?

```
$products = Product::query()
           ->withMax('details', 'price')
           ->withMax('detail_colors', 'stock')
```

Or you can define the relationship as such:

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Details::class)->ofMany('price', 'max');
}
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DetailColors::class)->ofMany('stock', 'max');
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Just out of curiosity: Which of the two options did you choose?

Comment: i have hasmany relationship. and i never see aggregate functions. just i use functions. thank you